# Korea: Visa required to go to the city while in transit in Seoul for a Philippine citizen?

Tags: visas, transit, filipino-citizens, seoul, korean-air

Hi I'm traveling to Uzbekistan and have 12 hours layover in Seoul via Korean Airlines. Do I need a visa to go out of the airport for sightseeing? I'm a Philippine passport holder.

Answer (score 4):

Visa is **NOT** required to transit through Incheon Airport (Seoul) for Nationals of the Philippines, under the following conditions:

- Participate in the [Transit Tourism Program](https://www.airport.kr/ap_cnt/en/trn/tour/trtour/trtour.do) (Advertised as free, but you have to pay 10 US dollars as an entry-procedure fee). You will have to [make a reservation in advance](https://www.cyberairport.kr/contents/eng/trans/tour/tour/reservation/index.jsp).
- Hold an airline ticket for transit within 72 hours.
- Stay only in the possible destination for tourists of Seoul (Seoul, Incheon, Gyeonggi Province)

Sources: [hikorea.go.kr](http://www.hikorea.go.kr/pt/InfoDetailR_en.pt?categoryId=2&parentId=385&catSeq=401&show)

Comment: All three conditions must be met?

Comment: @JoErNanO i do not know, it is an old answer i forgot..

Comment: AFAIK Bullet point 1 is one criteria, and 2 + 3 is another one. Need to dig further tho....