# Does a Filipina need a transit visa for South Korea?

Tags: transit-visas, south-korea, filipino-citizens

I'm a Filipina going home to the Philippines this coming April 27 by Jeju Air via Muan (MWX). Do I need a transit visa?

Comment: As far as I can tell Jeju Air does not fly to anywhere in the Philippines from Muan. What is your actual itinerary? Include your departure airport and transit airports.

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate of the above question, as the OP doesn't state that they have a Canadian visa, it is however a duplicate of of [Korea: Visa required to go to the city while in transit in Seoul for a Philippine citizen?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44194/korea-visa-required-to-go-to-the-city-while-in-transit-in-seoul-for-a-philippin)